# Changing the "user-agent" header using selenium with phantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to log into a form with selenium, and getting a weird error. I'm positive it has to do with the user-agent header, but if not, I'd like to know how to do it anyways.

Here's the function that logs in the form:

```
def log_in_phantom(username, password, url):
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS) 
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (<My user-agent>)
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities = dcap)
    browser.get(url)
    browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    username = browser.find_element_by_id("username")
    if username.is_displayed():
        username.send_keys(username)

    password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
    if password.is_displayed():
        password.send_keys(password)

    button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-default")
    if button.is_displayed:
        button.click()

    session = browser.session_id
    print(browser.current_url)
```

Here's what I get when I run the function:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Error                   Message => 'Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated'
 caused by Request => {<bunch of cookie data>}
```

In this cookie data, I notice that

```
{"User-agent":"Python-urllib/3.5}
```

So my attempt at changing the header wasn't successful. Am I using desired capabilities right? Something else I'm missing? I'm new to web scraping so it really could be anything.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Are you sure there are no other elements with `id="username"`?

Comment: There is another one, which is a hidden field.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

An another hidden field having the `id="username"` is causing problems here.

Ideally, you should make your locator more specific to match the visible element, for instance:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.login-form #username")
```

You can also filter out the visible element this way:

```
username = next(element for element in driver.find_elements_by_id("username") 
                if element.is_displayed())
username.send_keys("test")
```

You might also need to add an explicit wait before searching for the element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
)
```

Comment: The structure of the visible and hidden field are similar, so I tried the iteration. For some reason I'm getting a 'StopIteration'. I know the visible field's id is username

Comment: That probably won't work, because PhantomJS (v1.x?) has a bug, where only the first matched id is used for the selector regardless how specific that selector is. It can happen that no element is found at all. `"div.login-form [id='username']"` might be a better idea.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks! Let's see if the wait+filtering the visible element would help here..